# Can't add a new column in the dataset using Python (Lambda)

Tags: python, lambda

Trying to add a 'Month_Year' column in this frame where Jan 2020 can be shown as 01-01-2020, 01-02-2020’ for February 2020 and so on. Using lambda function

```
    Year    Month

0   2020    Jan
1   2020    Jan
2   2020    Jan
3   2020    Jan
4   2020    Jan
```

[The dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxkgt.png)

I tried this

```py
data['Month_Year']=data['Month_Year'].apply(lambda val:"01-01-2020" if val == "Jan")
```

but this wont work as I have 'Year' column as well to take reference of year as well and above method I feel is manual

Answer (score 0):

Simply concat them using a `+` operator

```
df['Month_Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Month'].astype(str)
```